# Stop two different forms from being submitted without one check box

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I need to have two separate forms. Sometimes dynamically I want to have two side by side and other times just one so I need them to be marked by the same Terms and Conditions checkbox. So far using different articles I learnt you can target multiple elements in jQuery using `$(".one, .two")` however the below code stops either forms from submitting.

```
<form method="post" id="options-select1">
    .....
</form>
<form method="post" id="options-select2">
    .....
</form>
<div class="termsconditions">
    <label>
        <input id="tc1" type="checkbox" />
        I accept the <a href="/privacy/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    </label>
</div>

<script>
    $("#options-select1, #options-select2").submit(function(e) {
        if (!$('tc1:checked').length) {
            alert("Please accept our terms and conditions");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Typo: you're missing the `#` from the checkbox selector: `$('#tc1:checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your code which is causing jQuery to fail in finding the element.

You've forgotten the `#` from the selector `$('tc1:checked')`.

**Fixed code**

```
<form method="post" id="options-select1">
    .....
</form>
<form method="post" id="options-select2">
    .....
</form>
<div class="termsconditions">
    <label>
        <input id="tc1" type="checkbox" />
        I accept the <a href="/privacy/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    </label>
</div>

<script>
    $("#options-select1, #options-select2").submit(function(e) {
        if (!$('#tc1:checked').length) { //Note the change here
            alert("Please accept our terms and conditions");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Facepalm - thank you! Will mark as right in 7 mins

Comment: @Bysander No problem, I hope that solved the issue at hand